# Android 4.2 - LD_PRELOAD supported or not?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-4.2-jelly-bean, ld-preload

I wonder if LD_PRELOAD is now supported with the newer Android-versions?

At the time of 4.0 ICS it wasn't, and in the documentation (NDK docs/SYSTEM-ISSUES.html) there's still:

```
No support for LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LD_PRELOAD, RTLD_LOCAL and many other options.
```

But some days ago I have used LD_LIBRARY_PATH on my Android 4.2 Galaxy Nexus and it worked (!).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can recall getting one of those to work, but one wonders what you plan to do with it - during normal Android operation, exec() is not really used, so there isn't much opportunity for such a setting to have an effect.  If you want to know definitively, check the sources, run strings on the linker binary, or test it.

Comment: I have never used LD_PRELOAD before, but it wonder if I could do something like this in android: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7795

Comment: But use it on what?   If you are dealing with proper Android code, you'd be loading a jni library into an existing process, in which case you can simply load the library with the replacement functions first - though beware that most of the system libraries are pre-loaded long before the first line of code you wrote runs.  The case where linker preload variables would actually apply is if you are actually executing binaries - operating more in the unix tradition than the android one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has worked on engineering builds (a.k.a. rooted devices) for quite a while. The problem is that this does not help for production builds - not because the loader is changed, but because the environment for your app is secured.

Comment: Hm yes, my device is a rooted one. Does this also mean, that I can assume that LD_LIBRARY_PATH (or better LD_PRELOAD) exists on "all" routed devices? I have already accepted, that my app will require are rooted device (sadly). As I already sad - I don't even know if LD_PRELOAD would work, I'm new at this.

Comment: Looking at AOSP bionic/linker/linker.c, `LD_PRELOAD` is not parsed.  The same proves that you can assume that changes to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will be respected by the loader on all rooted devices. See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/m6OddFQINxs and https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/2iy4zeyoVKU. Essentially, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is parsed when the loader (or the process, if you care) starts up, which can be controlled only on rooted devices.

Comment: Thank you for your response, that helped. Now, I have to look if I can  do something with this :)

Comment: What do you need to achieve?

Comment: I would like to capture outgoing audio and stream it to remote speakers. But in general, I would like to learn how android works. This evening, I found something about libaudio.so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430045/is-android-always-using-tinyalsa

Comment: It would be kind of you, if you could look into this again. :)

Comment: @erbdex: Not that something really happened in the last 12 months about it, except that all of us got 1 year older and wiser ;-) What do you expect from reopening this discussion? You can stream all audio output elsewhere (e.g. to external speakers) with a custom ROM, or on a rooted device. And anyways, tweaking `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is unlikely to help.

Comment: What [eriksen](https://github.com/mariusaeriksen/trickle) did was to exploit the unix's dynamic loader's pre-loading functionality (`LD_PRELOAD`) to place Trickle's code as a middle-ware between the socket calls and `libc` implementation to achieve rate-limiting.

I want to do the same thing on android.So i am looking for an authoritative take on `LD_PRELOAD`'s support on android.

Answer (score 6):

Although the offical NDK-r9d documentation still says the same, but it turns out that LD_PRELOAD does work on rooted devices.
Run

```
adb shell
setprop wrap.com.xyz.yourapp LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/your/library.so
stop
start
```

after pushing the library to the device.
I tried it successfully on ANDROID-19 emulator to provide alternate definition of a function.

Check out this link -
http://cedricvb.be/post/intercepting-android-native-library-calls/

Comment: Too late for me, but definitely a good hint and very interesting :)

Comment: Awesome answer.  There's one gotcha though that a property value must be no bigger than 91 characters...so you need to make sure the path/to/your/library.so is short (especially if you want multiple libraries).