# Is Android always using "tinyALSA"?

Tags: android, audio

Today I found out, that I could write a `libaudio.so` and put it in my Android's folder /system/lib/ for custom audio-handling.

My device, a Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.2 is using `tinyAlsa` and has a `libtinyalsa.so`.
So I think I could use this project (from the father of `tinyAlsa`) to build a custom libaudio.so: https://github.com/broonie/tinyhardware

But: Does anyone know, if the `tinyAlsa` is a samsung or omap special thing, or has any newer android-version that type of audio-handling? So, would my custom `libaudio.so` be portable on other phones?

If not, does anyone know where I can find a `libaudio.so` which works with default `ALSA`?
I know that "AlsaMixer" from Android-market uses it but I will compile it on my own.

With kind regards & thanks in advance.

Comment: To people who drop in here from Google, according to the [source.android.com](http://source.android.com/devices/audio/index.html) page, TinyALSA is recommended when ALSA in the kernel is used for sound output, as the standard ALSA userspace library is LGPL licensed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android devices do not always use tinyalsa and there's no requirement or recommendation for them to do so. However, all Nexus devices use tinyalsa and there are no plans to change this.

- from the tinyalsa author

Comment: Yearh, I've studied every line of your code, Simon :) Thanks!