# Why is tinyALSA preferred over libasound?

Tags: android, audio, alsa

In latest Android releases, the `AOSP` release typically comes with `tinyALSA` and `tinyCompress`. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430045/is-android-always-using-tinyalsa), Simon has mentioned that all Nexus devices shall support `tinyALSA`.

My question is why is android not integrating `libasound` which has all features required for an audio sub-system as compared to `tinyALSA`? Is it mainly due to the licensing issues as indicated in [source.android.com](http://source.android.com/devices/audio.html) site?

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak on the behalf of the Android developers, but if I had to guess it's because `ALSA` has a very old API that hasn't changed due to backwards compatibility reasons.

If you're choosing an audio system where backwards compatibility isn't a concern, the best thing to do is start with a clean slate and a more modern API.

This is consistent with their approach for `X.Org Server` - completely throw out the system and replace it with [something better](http://source.android.com/devices/graphics.html#render) although one could argue that this was done because X.Org wasn't built with touch screens in mind.

Lastly as you mentioned, Google recommends `tinyALSA` over `ALSA` because of the license.

Comment: Thanks Martin.. Your response is great and I share a lot of your views. However, I have heard a counter argument that `tinyALSA` doesn't have the list of features that `libaudio` has and hence, `libaudio` is preferred. Hence, I am caught with this paradox on what were the __technical reasons__ behind the decision to adopt `tinyALSA`.

Comment: The only other information I could find is that Simon (author of tinyALSA) is a Google employee. Here's the initial commit of tinyALSA into Android: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/tinyalsa/+/edff708e3129d7d8e05bbdfb624af97a3264a332 - I think you might have better luck contacting some of the AOSP devs on Google+ or Twitter.